# Serial.println Sensor Value and text in one line

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide

**How do I put the sensor value and text on the one line in the serial monitor.**

I just want Pot Value 30 to show in the serial console. What am I doing wrong?

```
Serial.println("POT value ")(sensorValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just do two Serial prints:

```
Serial.print("POT value ");
Serial.println(sensorValue);
```

The `.print` prints without moving to a new line, the `.println` moves to a new line.

If you want to be more fancy and don't mind the processing and memory overhead, you can use `snprintf` to format the string:

```
char temp[15];
snprintf(temp, 15, "POT value %4d", sensorValue);
Serial.println(temp);
```

You can read more about `sprintf` and formatting here:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/ (function parameters)
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ (formatting options)

**Note that there is no floating point support in the standard library for the Arduino - so you can't use %f etc.**

Comment: Thanks Mate perfect, i have only just started on this. Thanks for your help it worked!